# MapQuest JS API - get directions by sticking closely to list of points

Tags: javascript, routes, geocoding, path-finding, mapquest

I have certain **points (locations)** which my app has to pass through every time.
I also have a **road network** (composed of thousands of points).
I need to force my main road to go **as close as possible** to the network.
I've tried using MQ's ControlPoints but they do not seem to work.
Are there any alternatives/algorithms I could use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution.
I am using MapQuest's Directions API "Route control points" functionality.